# consuming WCF service with different environments

Tags: c#, wcf

Currently I am consuming WCF service by adding service reference. My current .svc file is `https://myservice.local/NameService.svc`

I consume it like

```
var serv = new NameServiceClient();
```

What happens when I get different URLs for different environments like production or testing. Do I need to define it somewhere? What would be best way?

Comment: @L-Three can you give me some link or example on how to do it?

Comment: Sure: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=WCF+example&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=2cVJVYibKc7-aOT6gMAF

Comment: @L-Three I have googled but cant find exactly what to search. Please can you give me good links if you know.

Comment: Are the different urls accessable on the same machine? e.g. https://myservice.local/NameService.svc, https://myservice.local/production/NameService.svc,https://myservice.local/test/NameService.svc? Or on different machines? Please give more content to your question, so the poeople can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I am having similar issue. @James where you able to find the answer?